# How can I create a custom HTML report from scratch for selenium tests

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver, report, log4net

I am asking this question in hopes that I will be pointed in the right direction as far as opensource tools/code are concerned in my effort to generate an HTML report similar to that of ExtentReports and the report created by Specflow (cucumber for .Net) for my selenium based automation tests.  Someone recommended Log4Net to log my automation steps, but as far as I can tell this creates just a log file.  I want to beautify my logged steps with pass/fail, name of tests, etc. into a pretty report.  I am unsure what tools and how to do it. Can you please provide me some guidance.

Comment: Why not just write it yourself?  HTML is easy and should work fine for a report.

Comment: [Here are some tips](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/08/printable-reports-using-only-css-and-html/) for printable reports you might find helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with ExtentReports or the one that Specflow generates?

Comment: How do you write out html through c#?